Specifying "From" field using Gmail API with service account with domain-wide authority (Python)
I have a webapp sending mail through the Gmail API using a service account that is impersonating a user account (user@site.com) through domain-wide access.
The emails are sending fine, but I want my emails to have a custom "From" field (say, "Custom From" <custom.from@site.com>).
However, spoofing the "From" tag in my MIMEText message doesn't change that the emails are sent with user@site.com in the "From" field. I suspect when the service account impersonates the user account, it overrides the MIME message fields? My question is if we can change this behaviour. Perhaps there are some anti-spoofing mechanisms built into the API?
Below is the relevant code.
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            'path/to/service/account/file.json', 
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'])
creds = creds.with_subject('user@site.com')  ## The impersonation

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(MIMEText("<h1>Test message</h1>", 'html'))
msg.attach(MIMEText("Test message", 'plain'))
msg['Subject'] = 'Test subject'
msg['Bcc'] = 'recipient@recipient.com'

msg['reply-to'] = 'custom.from@site.com'  ## This is fine
msg['From'] = '"Custom From" <custom.from@site.com>'  ## The custom "From" field that gets overridden

create_message = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_bytes()).decode()}
service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=create_message).execute()

and the received email:
...
MIME-Version: 1.0
reply-to: custom.from@site.com
From: user@site.com
...


Messages are sent from the user who is authenticated.
The only way to change the from to that would be to delegate to that user
creds = creds.with_subject('custom.from@site.com')  


Thanks for the response, but I know that messages are sent from the authenticated user. My question however is whether the "From" field can be spoofed to look like it came from someone else.

it can not be spoofed.  This ability was removed years ago. It is sent from the authenticated user and only the authenticated user
